# Sharing providers across terraform environments

Tags: terraform

I have some terraform scripts to deploy certain resources.

My app is a rest api which takes a request, and creates an appropriate folder, and copies all the scripts and initializes an environment dedicated to the requester using `-from-module` option.

The problem I have is that, this causes an installation to take place everytime a new environment is created for a new user, even though the only difference between environments is their state.

How can I achieve having those common files (mostly provider binaries) in one folder, and making every newly created environment point to the common files somehow and not install everytime?

I am aware of workspaces, but they don't work in my case since you can only be in single workspace at a given time, I have to lock all other users from doing anything related to terraform.

Comment: So the issue is state file locking? Provider caching? Something else?

Comment: It is that I have to install all of the providers everytime I initialize a new environment dedicated to the requester, which is both very time consuming and also memory inefficient due to installation of providers at each initialization.

Comment: Do you think this could help: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file?

Comment: Provider installation config was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the question states can be achieved with (based on the comments) [the provider installation configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#provider-installation).